# Custom admin for many-to-many field

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model `Question` which can have several `Answer` instances, each one with a given coefficient.

What I want is an admin in which I can add as many answers as I want, and creating a new one everytime one is added.

I tried with a many-to-many field, as shown below, but the default admin is a multiple select with all the answers in the db.

What I would like ideally is a button "add answer" in my Question admin, which would allow me to create a new answer and add it to my question.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

```
class Question(models.Model):
    answer = models.ManyToManyField(Response)

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    coefficient = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be interested in [Admin Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) form.

In this case you need to remove the ManyToMany field and add
a ForeignKey field to your Answer model and then tell the admin
to add an 'inline' admin form to your Question admin view.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.TextField()
    coefficient = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py

```
class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Answer


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerInline,]
```

This should do exactly what you asked for.

In the Question object you will have a 'answer_set' object which behave like
a ManyToMany handler.

The following example explain how to get a queryset containing all the answer related to your question.

```
my_question.answer_set.all()
```